# Solving nonlinear equations with "solve", incorrect solution

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am testing MATLAB capabilities in solving equations for a project that I intend to do, so I gave it a test run with something simple, but the results that it gives me are incorrect. I tried to solve two non-linear equations with two unknowns, one of the solutions is correct the other is not.

```
syms theta d x y

eq1 = d * cos(theta) == x;
eq2 = d * sin(theta) == y;

sol = solve(eq1, eq2, theta, d)

sol.theta
sol.d
```

The solutions for d are correct, but for theta I get:

```
 -2*atan((x - (x^2 + y^2)^(1/2))/y)
 -2*atan((x + (x^2 + y^2)^(1/2))/y)
```

And the correct answer for theta is simply atan(y/x)

Then when I evaluate these solutions with x = 1, y = 0, I get:

```
eval(sol.d)
eval(sol.theta)

d = 1, -1
theta = NaN, -3.1416
```

Solutions for d are correct, but theta in that scenario should be 0.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: solving it by hand it looks like this: Divide the y equation by the x equation

```
y/x = (d * sin(theta)) / (d * cos(theta))
y/x = sin(theta)/cos(theta)
y/x = tan(theta)
theta = atan(y/x)
```

Even if matlab solves it in some other way and gets a different expression, it should still yield the same final result when I use numbers and it PARTIALLY does.

For x = 1 and y = 0, theta should be 0, => this doesnt work, it gives NaN (explanation bellow)

for x = 1 and y = 1, theta should be 45 degrees => this works

for x = 0 and y = 1 theta should be 90 degrees => this works

And I just checked it again with the 45 and 90 degree values for x and y and it works, but for x = 1 and y = 0 it still gives NaN as one of the answers and that is because it gets a 0/0 from the way it is expressing it

```
-2*atan((x - (x^2 + y^2)^(1/2))/y)
-2*(1 - (1^2 + 0^2))^(1/2)/0 
-2*(1 - 1)^(1/2)/0 
0/0
```

but if its in the form of atan(y/x) the result is

```
theta = atan(0/1) 
theta = atan(0)
theta = 0
```

Comment: *And the correct answer for theta is simply atan(y/x)*, are you sure?

Comment: I am certain, solving it by hand it looks like this: Divide the y equation by the x equation => (y/x) = (d * sin(theta)) / (d * cos(theta)) the d's cancel each other => y/x = sin(theta)/cos(theta) => y/x = tan(theta) => theta = atan(y/x). Even if matlab solves it in some other way and gets a different expression, it should still yield the same final result when I use numbers but it doesnt. For x = 1 and y = 0, theta should be also 0, for x = 1 and y = 1, theta should be 45 degrees, for x = 0 and y = 1 theta should be 90 degrees.

Comment: Ok I just checked it again with the 45 and 90 degree values for x and y and it works, but for x = 1 and y = 0 it still gives NaN as one of the answers and that is because it gets a 0/0 from the way it is expressing it => (1 - (1^2 + 0^2))^(1/2)/0 => (1 - 1)^(1/2)/0 => 0/0, but if its in the form of atan(y/x) the result is atan(0/1) => atan(0)  = 0

Comment: yeah but if you take an example where `d<1` and `x>1` then there will be no solution for `eq1`.

Comment: @obchardon that is true, but I am not doing that, the expression and answers that I get for d are correct, but I dont get correct values for theta when it should be 0 degrees as I have explained in my last answer, so ti seems that this is the only issue at the moment. I have also updated my main post. d is not interfering with theta.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to solve this:

```
syms a b theta d real

eq1 = a==d * cos(theta) ;
eq2 = b==d * sin(theta) ;

[sol] = solve([eq1 eq2],[d theta] ,'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints', true,'Real',true,'ReturnConditions',true);
```

Comment: Well, seems like the same thing, I dont know what your additional arguments do, but yeah. However, it still gives an incorrect answer for theta, it gives the same answer as mine does and the correct answer for theta is atan(y/x) or atan(b/a) in your case, but it still gives 
    -2*atan((a - (a^2 + b^2)^(1/2))/b)
    -2*atan((a + (a^2 + b^2)^(1/2))/b)
Which is not correct.

Comment: @Darkbound You should set `IgnoreAnalyticConstraints` to false. This will give you the conditions in `sol` for which the found solution is true. For any a and b you will see that it will give `b~=0`, but if you specify a and b to be 1 and 0, you will find the right solution (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=q*cos(t)%3D1+and+q*sin(t)%3D0)).

Comment: @rinkert I just tried it and it still gives me NaN for b = 0, a = 1.
sol = solve(eq1, eq2, d, theta, 'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints', false)

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay. i'm also confused here.

Answer (score 0):

When solving the equations with symbolic `x` and `y`, the solver will find a solution with a certain condition, which can be obtained using the argument `'ReturnCondition'`:

```
syms x y theta d real

eq1 = d*cos(theta) == x;
eq2 = d*sin(theta) == y;

sol = solve([eq1; eq2],[d theta],'ReturnConditions',true);
```

This gives the following result for `sol`

```
>> sol.d
  (x^2 + y^2)^(1/2)
 -(x^2 + y^2)^(1/2)

>> sol.theta
  2*pi*k - 2*atan((x - (x^2 + y^2)^(1/2))/y)
  2*pi*k - 2*atan((x + (x^2 + y^2)^(1/2))/y)

>> sol.parameters
  k

>> sol.conditions
  y ~= 0 & in(k, 'integer')
  y ~= 0 & in(k, 'integer')
```

As you can see, y = 0 does not fulfill this general solution given by the solver, resulting in your problem for y = 0. You can find solutions for y = 0 by either making `y` numeric instead of symbolic, or by adding an assumption:

```
syms x y theta d real
assume(y==0)
sol = solve([eq1; eq2],[d theta],'ReturnConditions',true);
```

I guess its easier to just set y=0 numeric, for this one condition, since there are already 4 possible solutions and conditions for the three lines above.

Comment: The reason I am solving it like this is, because I will eventually be solving it for many different x and y, I wouldnt know when and if y will ever be 0, but its possible that it is. For example I may have t = 0:0.01:10, x = 5t and y = sin(t) and using these x and y vectors I have to find the theta and d vectors that correspond to them, so this is not just one scenario, I was just testing whats going on with this simple example. Also note that the x and y equations I just used are random illustrative ones, I don't know if they will actually work in this case.

Comment: So in that sense, I need the solution to be reliable without me having to stitch it (or at least if I have to stitch it, it should work for any variation of these equations). Also my x and y equations may change, I want to create a program that will be able to build these equations and solve them based on a number of parameters, so what equations I will end up with is completely non-predictable, there may be 10-20-30 different variations of these equations that I can have, so is it possible that it becomes reliable?

Comment: Ah got you. Perhaps you better can switch to something like Mathematica, which is much better for symbolic work. Or some open source alternative, don't have any experience with them though.

Comment: Yea I dont have experience with others either thats why I headed towards Matlab, well I'll see how it goes and try to stitch it in a more general way somehow. Thanks